# VBS error: "Expected end of statement"

Tags: vbscript

I must be overlooking something painfully obvious. The following code fails on the Next line with the error message "Expected end of statement":

```
Option Explicit

    GetB

Sub GetB()
    Dim i

    For i = 1 to 2
        Msgbox i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Found it. The repetition of the loop variable ("i") in the Next statement, which is legal and optional in every other BASIC-like (B*SIC?) language, is illegal in VBS.

The code should read:

```
Option Explicit
GetB

Sub GetB()
    Dim i    
    For i = 1 to 2
        Msgbox i
    Next     
End Sub
```